# How to add slider to image and content?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to add slider to image and content. I have tried using different tutorials but they are mostly for images only (not along with content) like carousels. I need your suggestions here to add slider for both images and content placed beside eachother.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/HebleV/pen/MVYaey)

**Code for index.html**

```
<div class="container slider-border mt-4">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-left" style="font-size:24px"></i>
<div class="row " id="oneImg">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h4jk5s6ca0suqu/pic2.jpg?raw=1" class="img-fluid" width="400" height="300">     
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>John D</h4>
    <h5>Software Developer</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="secondImg">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h4jk5s6ca0suqu/pic2.jpg?raw=1" class="img-fluid" width="400" height="300">     
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>John D</h4>
    <h5>Software Developer</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h4jk5s6ca0suqu/pic2.jpg?raw=1" class="img-fluid" width="400" height="300">     
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h4>John D</h4>
    <h5>Software Developer</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
 <i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="font-size:24px"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: In your Codepen example you never used your Style classes like `slide-content` or `slider` anywhere in your HTML markup.

Comment: Hi. I have updated codepen link . I need help with JS.

Comment: Actually, the problem is, in your JS you have defined functions for elements which is nowhere in the your HTML page. If you can go with jQuery, I can give you a solution for your desired content slider.

Comment: Yes Jquery is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple jQuery slider code.

```js
$(function(){
    
    var totalSlides = 3;
    var slideNumber = 1;
    setInterval(function(){
        if(slideNumber < totalSlides){
            if($("#slider-4").length > 0){
                $("#slider-4").hide("slide", {
                  "direction" : "left",
                  "duration" : 400
                });
            }
            $("#slider-"+ slideNumber +"").hide("slide", {
                  "direction" : "left",
                  "duration" : 400
                });
            slideNumber++;
            $("#slider-"+ slideNumber +"").show("slide", {
                  "direction" : "right",
                  "duration" : 400
                });
           
        } else {
            $("#slider-3").hide("slide", {
                  "direction" : "left",
                  "duration" : 400
                });
            slideNumber = 0;
            $("#slider-4").show("slide", {
                  "direction" : "right",
                  "duration" : 400
                });
        }
    }, 8000);
    
});
```

```css
.slider-wrapper{
overflow-x: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
}
.slides{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
}

#slider-1{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <div class="slides" id="slider-1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h4jk5s6ca0suqu/pic2.jpg?raw=1" class="img-fluid" width="400" height="300">     
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>John A</h4>
        <h5>Software Developer</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slides" id="slider-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h4jk5s6ca0suqu/pic2.jpg?raw=1" class="img-fluid" width="400" height="300">     
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>John D</h4>
        <h5>Software Developer</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slides" id="slider-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h4jk5s6ca0suqu/pic2.jpg?raw=1" class="img-fluid" width="400" height="300">     
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>John B</h4>
        <h5>Software Developer</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slides" id="slider-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h4jk5s6ca0suqu/pic2.jpg?raw=1" class="img-fluid" width="400" height="300">     
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>John C</h4>
        <h5>Software Developer</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. It doesn't slide. It just fades in and out. Am I right ?

Comment: Check the edit. Added slide in place of Fade using jQuery UI.

Comment: Wow this is simply amazing. Thanks man. just a question. Can I like add arrows to the sides of slide and move it when clicked ?

Comment: Ha ha ha. Do something on your own too man, lol. Add `hide` and `show` functions to the `click` event of your buttons. Do some research and ask that in another question if not successful.

Comment: lolz.I did not ask you to do it man. All I asked is if I can carry on from here if I want it that way. But thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for owl carousel or slick carousel. They're easy to use and will do exactly what you want.